# Is there a way to find out when the last time was when my laptop used dedicated graphics instead of integrated graphics?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I use a laptop with a lower-mid end dedicated graphics card (AMD R7 M265). I don't play games or do any video-editing. Is there a way to see when was the last time my laptop actually used the dedicated graphics card instead of the integrated graphics card built into my Intel i3 4030U?

I want to know this because I'm choosing a new laptop and I want to see if I really needed the graphics card on my current laptop. I do play a few games every now and then but I've been able to live without them for a while now.

Comment: I assume then that your laptop automatically switched between integrated and dedicated graphics processors? Please amend your question if this is the case.

Comment: Yes, it automatically switches between integrated and dedicated graphics processors depending upon what I'm doing.